# Reference to a Silverlight Class Library

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, class-library

i'm building a Service-Client application using Silverlight and WCF, i have a Model project (which contains POCOs) on the Server side, and i wanted to share those same entities to the Silverlight-Client Application, and i thought, hey! I can change the Model project to be a Silverlight class library, and it should work just fine.

I did the change and now, i'm able to add the references however it is getting the exclamation mark like when the reference is not resolved... and if you take a look at the properties the value of "Resolved" is set to "False",  this is causing the following Code Analysis Errors:

[CA0058](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244739%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)
[CA0001][2]

Please note:
this is not the typical question about referencing a Typical Class Library from a Silverlight project (i Know that can't be done), but the other way arround.

Answer (score 3):

It should work fine (unlike what Wayne says, you can actually reference Silverlight assemblies from projects that target the full .NET Framework).  However, you may have references in this project that the full .NET Framework can't load (you generally need to keep your references to the most base types).  You've got two alternative options.

1. Create two class library projects (one targeting Silverlight, the other the .NET Framework), and share the files between them, as I discuss in this article: http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Building-a-Silverlight-Line-Of-Business-Application-Part-3.aspx
2. Try out the Portable Library Tools (currently in beta): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sburke/archive/2011/01/23/3-screen-coding-is-here-portable-library-tools-allow-you-to-target-multiple-net-platforms-with-one-binary.aspx

Hope this helps...

Chris Anderson

Comment: Very interesting...  not what i was thinking of, i have had worked with WPF before and share the model between the client and the service is really cool, i was trying to do the same with silverlight, since the Silverlight client is only going to do a two tier application i think i might as well just use the proxy generated clases on the actual silverlight application.

Comment: did i just forgot to say thanks?  thank you very much Chris, i really appreciate your comment

Comment: I think I stand by my (admittedly incomplete) answer - just because it's technically possible to add a reference to a SL assembly from a CLR project and get it to compile, it doesn't mean you should. You're going to potentially be in a world of pain at runtime. Let the compiler help you - and use the Add as Link... approach to share code files between two projects that each target their appropriate runtime.

Answer (score 2):

For the same reason you can't reference a CLR assembly from a Silverlight project, you can't reference a Silverlight assembly from a CLR project -- they're different runtimes.

Comment: That's not cool at all... i was trying to avoid code duplicity and when i thought of that it seemed to have seense, thanks for your comment!